# CM Hodge structures

Tags: hodge-theory, complex-multiplication

There are several definitions of Hodge structures with complex multiplication. One of them is the following:

**Definition**. A Hodge structure $H$ is CM if it is polarizable and its Mumford-Tate group is abelian.

Then one shows that $End(H)$ (as Hodge structures) is a CM field.

But imagine one consider instead Hodge strctures $H$ such that $End(H)$ contains a number field $F$ with $[F: \mathbb{Q}]=\dim H$. My question is:

Does this imply that $F$ is a CM field?

I don't have the impression this is true, but I'm a bit confused, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is this related to my question?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly. In fact it is easy to see that F need not be a CM field. For example, let $H = H^1(E)^{\oplus 2}$ where $E$ is an ellipic curve with CM by a field K. Then $End(H)$ is the ring of 2x2 matrices over K, so contains all quadratic extensions of K.

Comment: Dear ulrich, I am confused. In your example $H$ is polarisable (as sum of polarisables), and its MT-group is abelian (since it is identified with the MT-group of $H$). So, this would imply that $\text{End}(H)$ is a CM field, right? Where is my mistake?